# Android to Windows USB File Transfer Files Missing

Tags: android, windows, file, xamarin.android, usb

I recently created an app that records data to external storage (that is to say myFilePath = Environment.getExternamStorageDirectory().toString() + "mypath/thisCollectionsFolder/myfile.data"). When I look for the file via airdroid or es file explorer I am able to find it after I'm done recording. However if I plug the phone into a windows PC via usb and navigate to mypath I am unable to see "thisCollectionsFolder" in explorer for a while.  If I let the phone "rest" for a while I'm then able to see the "thisCollectionFolder". Sometimes "myfile.data" is visible in "thisCollectionFolder" sometimes I have to let the phone "rest" for a while longer before I'm able to see it.

I've observed this behavior on a Nexus 6p and a Pixel 2 both running android 8 on two different windows PCs. I've tried restarting the phones after the files are written but this does not make this visible in explorer. Note my application is written using Xamarin and I make use of the dotnet System.IO classes for writing.

My questions are as follows

- Is this a known issue?
- Is there anything I can do in my app to ensure the files are visible immediately after they are written?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When an android device connects to a computer, the PC doesn't read
   the device's disk file data. It's mapped through the MTP service.
2. The mapping of data source Provider of Android in a media database:
   com.android.provider.media/databases/external.db.In this database,
   there is a files table. In this table, all records will be mapped by
   the MTP service to the file manager of the PC.
3. Meanwhile, the modifications we made on the PC were also made to the files table in the server first, and then the disk operation of the system will be triggered.

So,you can specify the path of a file, which is then scanned by the system and then synchronized to the PC after you records data to external storage.Use the mtehod `MediaScannerConnection` . Xamarin.Android has  corresponding method. For more detail you can refer [here](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection).